# Binding doesn't work in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, controls, dependency-properties

I have a wpf control named DataPicker which has a dependency property named SelectedDate.

In simple cases it works well but there is one case where binding fails and I can't understand why:   when i try to bind it inside a ListView.

For example, I have class (INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented)

```
public class TestClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

and try to bind sample collection like

```
public ObservableCollection<TestClass> Items { get; set; }
```

which has one element in it.

Binding looks like

```
 <Window x:Class="Neverov.Test.Window1"
         x:Name="this"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Neverov.Framework;assembly=Neverov.Framework">
     <Grid>        
         <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=Items}">
             <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>                     
                     <StackPanel>
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                             <local:DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay}"/>                             
                     </StackPanel>                     
                 </DataTemplate>
             </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and Name property works fine.

inside my DatePicker date value is shown this way:

```
<TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="SelectedDate" 
                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:DatePicker}}"
                 Mode="TwoWay"
                 Converter="{StaticResource DateTimeConverter}"
                 ConverterParameter="d">
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>    
</TextBox>
```

any ideas why this could happen?

More code of the DatePicker class: (some specific properties that I need I'll rather miss to keep code size not so large)

```
[TemplatePart(Name = PartPopup, Type = typeof(Popup))]
[TemplatePart(Name = PartMonthBack, Type = typeof(ButtonBase))]
[TemplatePart(Name = PartMonthForward, Type = typeof(ButtonBase))]
[TemplatePart(Name = PartDates, Type = typeof(Selector))]
[TemplatePart(Name = PartTextBox, Type = typeof(TextBox))]
[TemplatePart(Name = PartCheckBox, Type = typeof(CheckBox))]
[TemplatePart(Name = PartToggleButton, Type = typeof(ToggleButton))]
public class DatePicker : Control, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDate",
                                    typeof(DateTime?),
                                    typeof(DatePicker),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                                                                  FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                                                                  (sender, e) =>
                                                                  {
                                                                      var datePicker = sender as DatePicker;
                                                                      if (datePicker != null)
                                                                      {
                                                                          var oldValue = e.OldValue as DateTime?;
                                                                          DateTime selectedDateForPopup =
                                                                              datePicker.SelectedDate ??
                                                                              DateTime.Now;
                                                                          datePicker.CurrentlyViewedMonth =
                                                                              selectedDateForPopup.Month;
                                                                          datePicker.CurrentlyViewedYear =
                                                                              selectedDateForPopup.Year;
                                                                          datePicker.OnDateChanged(datePicker.SelectedDate, oldValue);                                                                              
                                                                          var popup = datePicker.GetTemplateChild(PartPopup) as Popup;
                                                                          if (popup != null)
                                                                              popup.IsOpen = false;
                                                                      }
                                                                  }));
   ... //a lot more not so important code here
}
```

Comment: what is the problem exactly? does that date not show up in the datePicker, or does the Selected Date in the datepicker not getting propagated to your TestClass object? In the latter case, you may want to add a Mode=TwoWay to your datepicker binding (i.e. - SelectedDate="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: SelectedDate in the DataPicker doesn't get to my TestClass object, and yes, Mode is set to TwoWay everywhere

Comment: are you modifying the source code of the DatePicker? or are you just posting it for our convenience?

Comment: yes, I'm just posting more of it; I already mentioned, that I just tried to decrease amount of code in post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.

It was not in wrong bindings or other difficult and uneven stuff, but, as it was legacy code, somewhere in code programmer made a mistake.

Thank for all!

Comment: Don't we all make mistakes from time to time ;)

Comment: yeah) but I spent about two days to fix this and became rather mad)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your properties throw the INotifyPropertyChanged event:

```
public class TestClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime date;

    public DateTime Date 
    { 
        get { return date; }
        set { date = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Date"); } 
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }   
}
```

And make your binding to the date also TwoWay:

```
<local:DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: they throws, of course, I just didn't mention it in post to decrease size of code in it

Comment: It seems that your types dont match.. You use a nullable type in your control, and a non nullable DateTime in your object. Also, please try the use normal a PropertyMetadata object.. My experience is that FrameworkPropertyMetadata objects do behave rather strangely from time to time..

Answer (score 2):

Check the output window for any data binding errors..

Probable errors:

- DataContext not set correctly.
- `ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=Items}` Isn't Items a property of the Window or a ViewModel class ?

Comment: DataContext is set correctly (Items of the collection are binded to list box's ItemsSource), this is just a simple test app, property is part of Window class, the problem is really something deeper I think

Comment: and no, I see no data binding errors in output window, that's just crazy)